# Multi view face detection

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, face-detection

I am working on a video processing project. Till now I have been using LBPfrontal face cascade for detecting human faces but the problem with them is they can't detect side views or tilted faces. is there any trained classifier for detecting this type of faces? or is their any efficient algorithm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For out of plane rotations (change in yaw similar to the "no" gesture) there is a trained cascade profile_face.xml that will work for left profiles. So first check for frontal faces, then check for left profiles, then mirror the image and check for right profiles (and reverse mirror the coordinates).

For in-plane rotations (change in roll, similar to head "bobbling") you most rotate the image maybe 30-45 degrees, perform frontal face detection, and then "un-rotate" the coordinates.

For head movement for the "yes" gesture (change in pitch). Detections will work for the frontal face detector.

Put all these detectors together in parallel in some clever efficient algorithm, use a GPU, and you can come up with a system that will detect a face at any angle. Perhaps add a skin detector into the mix the remove false accepts/rejects.

Comment: Or if you want to use a Kinect instead of a webcam and use Point Cloud Library instead of OpenCV, check this: http://pointclouds.org/blog/hrcs/aaldoma/index.php